# Authenticate to SFTP server in PHP with PuTTY .ppk key file

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I want to transfer files via SFTP using PHP.

The remote server provides the IP, username, and a password including PPK file with a passphrase. I'm able to log in using WinSCP, but in my php script I'm having trouble with `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()`

Can you please tell me what Im supposed to do with the given PPK file?
What are the public and private key I need to provide to authenticate?

Clear explanation is much appreciated. Thank you!

Code:

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($host, $port, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn,$username,$pub_key,$pri_key,$passphrase)){
  echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n";
}else{
  die('Public Key Authentication Failed');  
}
```

The public key I used came from PuTTYgen.
Converted PPK to PUB file.

Answer (score 1):

Function `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` accepts public and private key files in a common OpenSSH format.

To generate these files from PuTTY `.ppk` key file:

- Start [PuTTYgen](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen) and load your `.ppk` key.
- Use contents of *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file* for a public key file.
- Use *Conversions > Export OpenSSH key* menu command to generate private key file.

It does not matter where you save the files, as long as the webserver can access those.

---

There seems to be a [bug in PHP SSH2 functions that prevents loading encrypted private keys](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58573) (keys with passphrase).

The bug results in:

> ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for ... using public key: Callback returned error

---

If you want to use the private key, and you cannot fix SSH libraries, you can use [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) instead.

```
set_include_path("phpseclib");
require_once("Net/SSH2.php");
require_once("Crypt/RSA.php");

$privatekey = new Crypt_RSA();
$privatekey_data = file_get_contents($pri_key);

$privatekey->setPassword($passphrase);
if (!$privatekey->loadKey($privatekey_data, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1))
{
    die("Cannot load key");
}

$sftp = new Net_SSH2($host);

if (!$sftp->login($username, $privatekey))
{
    die("Cannot login");
}
```

phpseclib supports even .ppk keys, though I was not able to use encrypted .ppk key either. But encrypted OpenSSH keys works correctly. Note that you do not need a separate public key file with phpseclib.